# Equation Solver in C#

Tags: c#, math

Is there any open source library in c# for solving mathematical equations?

Example:

5*x= 10:
After parsing this string, I would receive the number 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Mathematical equations" is an extremely broad term.

If you only want to solve single linear equations, that's not very hard.  But if you want something more advanced, you need a powerful engine.

I'm not sure if it's free, but if you have complex math that you need solved, you'll probably want to look into [Wolfram Alpha](http://wolframalpha.com).  I see that they have an API that you can grab and access through typical REST services, so you can do this in C#.  I'm not sure if it's free, though - I know their site frequently advertises their full service.

You may be able to reverse engineer their free site sufficient to your needs.  To get you started, try [this URL](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=5%2ax=10)